# How can I pass an optional argument to an overloaded function in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have an overloaded function that I'm calling with an optional parameter. I'm having trouble figuring out how to get Typescript to find the errors correctly in this.

```js
function inner<T>(innerArg: T) {
    function foo(): T;
    function foo(a: boolean): T & { a: boolean };
    // function foo(a?: boolean): T | T & { a: boolean };
    function foo(a?: boolean) {
        return a ? { ...innerArg, a } : innerArg;
    }
    return foo;
}

function wrapper<T>(outerArg: T, a?: boolean) {
    return inner(outerArg)(a);  // Argument of type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'.
}

const arg = { b: 1 }

console.log(wrapper(arg).b);  // 1
console.log(wrapper(arg, true).a);  // true
console.log(wrapper(arg, true).b);  // 1

console.log(wrapper(arg).a);  // should generate compilation error
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-beta#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-WG84QgAW0xU-0QFFumDks0Q1KuIxgKjjUkQmAwcAwzCAA)

If I uncomment that fourth line, adding an overload signature with an optional, the error in the wrapper goes away. However, then I get an error from the third to last line,

```js
console.log(wrapper(arg, true).a);
```

which should be valid and which prints 'true'.

Is there a way of typing `inner` such that Typescript will correctly identify correct and incorrect usages of `inner` and `wrapper`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out; the trick is to add the type

```js
function foo(a?: boolean): T | T & { a: boolean };
```

for `foo`, and then to type `wrapper` with overloads:

```js
function wrapper<T>(outerArg: T): T;
function wrapper<T>(outerArg: T, a: boolean): T & { a: boolean };
function wrapper<T>(outerArg: T, a?: boolean) {
    return inner(outerArg)(a);
}
```

This creates a lot of redundancy with the types of `foo`, but it does work correctly.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-beta#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDMYCmAnAPAFQHwAUK6GAghgOYBciOAlIgN4BQibioksCHccBdGjgDcrdp2jwkwPgQCGNAEZ8ANmjlhBtRADImiBYmVw1GxAF9R7DuEk8Z-OQH4lq9ZqGIAPtr2MDribuFlbittzSss6BpppMYtZsGGhQIBhIcohO+gB0ecSY5BQANAYWiDQFZJShbOYJiMmp6bxwovXMEhGIAO4YcgAOA5i4hHAgUIWUQloineFSvf1DI-gE45PV1LSlhsaxs7r6e25mlvNci32Dw9hrG1PbOLsuRqdxLNZNaUhV6xOPOjyOjCNgAejBiCKIAAtmgwFBEHBgIgoABPYaIADk+2CPnAABM0MAUGgCVjkABnRBgOCIuSUykwChgOSKNSouCIAZyfpwzZIlHozE495YnLMDoQBCU+mURAAXn0ihoAEYLMxmNKwJSgjkVHAKARrisMPJKHQcooQeDIaqtTK9QajSbbuaSqiMCA0Ja5DbEBDPd6HTqnYbjcs3byPVAvT6rf7A-aQ7q1Prw67MO7fYnIZSABbjFQExAUeGYOSTRDSmEDGAqSuLTAYOAYZhAA)